# MSSQL How to handle null values to count them within pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, pivot, sql-null

I'm here again because I've another problem with pivot table that concerns with null values.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#exams') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #exams
END
GO


create table #exams (
id uniqueidentifier,
exam nvarchar(max),
technician nvarchar(max)
)



insert into #exams 
values 
(newid(),'Esame1','Tecnico1'),
(newid(),'Esame2','Tecnico1'),
(newid(),'Esame1','Tecnico2'),
(newid(),'Esame3','Tecnico1'),
(newid(),'Esame3','Tecnico2'),
(newid(),'Esame3','Tecnico3'),
(newid(),'Esame3','Tecnico1'),
(newid(),'Esame1',NULL)
```

I have to handle in some way null values in my reports.

With sum case clause I could do simply in this way:

```sql
 select
 exam,
 sum(case when technician = 'Tecnico1' then 1 else 0 end) as Tecnico1,
 sum(case when technician = 'Tecnico2' then 1 else 0 end) as Tecnico2,
 sum(case when technician = 'Tecnico3' then 1 else 0 end) as Tecnico3,
 sum(case when technician is null then 1 else 0 end) as Unknown 
 from #exams
 group by exam
 order by exam
```

| exam | Tecnico1 | Tecnico2 | Tecnico3 | Unkwnon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Esame1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Esame2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Esame3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

but using pivot table (thanks again to Tole1010) null values stay outside from my pivot

```sql
select * from (
    select id,exam,
           technician 
           from #exams
    ) as t
    pivot 
    (   count(id)
            for technician in (Tecnico1,Tecnico2,Tecnico3)
        ) as t
```

and I get only:

| exam | Tecnico1 | Tecnico2 | Tecnico3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Esame1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Esame2 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Esame3 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Is there a way to add a column to count those null values using pivot syntax?

Comment: You're right Lamu. Sorry. I missed from this forum from a lot of years and I forgot it. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically replace `null` with something else, that does not otherwise appear in the column:

```
select * from (
    select id, exam,
       coalesce(technician , 'Unknown') as technician
    from #exams
) as t
pivot (   
    count(id)
    for technician in (Tecnico1,Tecnico2,Tecnico3, Unknown)
) as t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7e93624717017fcfdf49f4cd48439115)**:

| exam | Tecnico1 | Tecnico2 | Tecnico3 | Unknown |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Esame1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Esame2 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Esame3 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |